# Hide div table's content based upon remaining space

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have two div boxes next to each other. The left box containing a "div table". When resizing the page, I want the content of the left div table to be hidden, e.g. overflow: hidden.
However, the left box contains the "remaining" space, whereas the right box has a width of 35%.

When the content of the div table is wider than "the remaining space" (width of the left box), than the right border of the table is not visible anymore.

I would like to hide the remaining of the image, but keep seeing the right border of the div table. Can this be done using div tables?

**HTML**

```
    <div class="table" id="containerRight">Some content on the right</div>
<div id="containerLeft">
    <div class="table" id="tableLeft">
        <div class="table-row">
            <div class="table-cell">
                <div style="width:14px;"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="table-cell">Some title</div>
            <div class="table-cell">
                <div style="width:14px;"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="table-row">
            <div class="table-cell"></div>
            <div class="table-cell">
                    <!-- This is the content of the LEFT table -->
                    <img src="http://oasis-church-nj.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/easter-egg.jpg" style="height:100px; width:500px;" />
            </div>
            <div class="table-cell"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="table-row">
            <div class="table-cell"></div>
            <div class="table-cell"></div>
            <div class="table-cell"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.table {
    display:    table;
    overflow:   hidden;
    border-collapse:    collapse;
}

.table-row {
    display:    table-row;
}

.table-cell {
    display:    table-cell;
    word-break: all;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#containerLeft {
    background: #F0F;
    position:   relative;
    display:    block;
    overflow:   hidden;
    margin:     0px 0px 15px 0px;
}

#containerRight {
    background: #FF0;
    position:   relative;
    min-width:  220px;
    max-width:  400px;
    width:      35%;
    height:     300px;
    float:      right;
    margin:     0px 0px 15px 15px;
}
```

Example can be found here. Make the HTML table wider and smaller, the right border will dissapear.
http://jsfiddle.net/gqmJ9/

Comment: Border?  Do you mean the strip of magenta background color?

Comment: See the table as 9 cells, 3 rows 3 colums. The center cell is the "content" whereas the outer 8 cells are what I would define as "border". Of cause in the final code they will be filled with images to show a nice box.

Answer (score 0):

May be this is what u want:

http://jsfiddle.net/Bh8hg/1/

Simply made a real border to the left div.

```
#containerLeft {
    background: #F0F;
    position:   relative;
    display:    block;
    overflow:   auto;
    margin:     0px 0px 15px 0px;
    border:     #F0F 15px solid;    //real border
}
```

also remove `<div style="width:14px;"></div>`,
it's not good idea to put `style` in html, hard to maintain.

Comment: Almost, I now also want to fill the boarder with a background image. The <div style="width:14px;"></div> was added to show that there actually was something on the left and right of the image :)